# Fortran - setting kind/precision of a variable at run time

Tags: fortran, precision

Is it possible to make a precision of a variable itself a variable that will be defined at a run time?
Say, if I try to compile:

```
      SUBROUTINE FOO( VARIABLE, PRECISION_VALUE )

      IMPLICIT NONE

      INTEGER(4) :: PRECISION_VALUE
      INTEGER(PRECISION_VALUE) :: VARIABLE

      RETURN
      END
```

the compiler output is:

```
    error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [PRECISION_VALUE]
          INTEGER(PRECISION_VALUE) :: VARIABLE
    --------------^
    compilation aborted for trial.f (code 1)
```

Anyway around it? I understand that not any arbitrary value can be used for `KIND`, but that's not my concern in this question.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560182/fortran-determine-variable-type or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257248/how-to-write-wrapper-for-allocate will help with what you want to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's not possible, type, kind and rank have to be known. However, you can define generic subroutine interfaces with implementations for all the kinds that you expect to be passed into a routine at runtime.