# "A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant." in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran

I try to introduce complex-valued array and variables in Fortran. For the following code

```
program 

   integer ::  i , j !two dimensional real array
   real(dp)  :: m1(3,2) 
   complex(dp) ::  a1(3,2),a2(3,2), c0, c1


   !assigning some values to the array numbers


   c0 = (1.0_dp, 0.0_dp)
   c1 = (0.000000001_dp, 0.0_dp)

   do i=1,3
      do j = 1, 2
         a1(i,j) = c0*i*j
      end do
   end do   

   do i=1,3
      do j = 1, 2
         a2(i,j) = c0*i*j + c1
      end do
   end do   

   do i=1,3
      do j = 1, 2
        if (dabs( dreal(a1(i,j)) - dreal(a2(i,j))) > 1.e-6 then
          write (*,*), 'warning',i,j, a1(i,j), a2(i,j)
        end if
      end do
   end do      

   write (*,*), a1(1,1), a2(1,1)




end program
```

ifort gives me

```
   complex(dp) ::  a1(3,2), a2(3,2)
-----------^
```

why complex(dp) requires compile-time constant and how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind parameter `dp` must be a constant, see [Fortran - setting kind/precision of a variable at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526500/fortran-setting-kind-precision-of-a-variable-at-run-time)

However, you do not have the same problem as in the link, you did not try to define `dp` at all! First, you must use `IMPLICIT NONE`, it is absolutely necessary for safe programming and the biggest problem with your code. Then it will tell you that the type of `dp` is not declared.

You just define the kind constant in one of the usual ways, as a constant. The most simple is:

```
program main

  !NECESSARY!
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
```

Note that I named the program `main`, you have to name your program. Or just omit the `program`.

More about defining real kinds can be found at [Fortran 90 kind parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter)

---

Another note: Forget `dabs()` and `dreal()`. `dabs()` is an old remnant of Fortran 66 and `dreal()` is not standard Fortran at all. Just use `abs` and either `dble()` or better `real( ,dp)`.

Comment: For clarity I would never recommend to not using the "program" statment.

Comment: Yes, it can be confusing.