# Allocating arrays of the same size

Tags: arrays, fortran, allocation

I'd like to allocate an array `B` to be of the same shape *and* have the same lower and upper bounds as another array `A`. For example, I could use

```
allocate(B(lbound(A,1):ubound(A,1), lbound(A,2):ubound(A,2), lbound(A,3):ubound(A,3)))
```

But not only is this inelegant, it also gets very annoying for arrays of (even) higher dimensions.

I was hoping for something more like

```
allocate(B(shape(A)))
```

which doesn't work, and even if this did work, each dimension would start at 1, which is not what I want.

Does anyone know how I can easily allocate an array to have the same size and bounds as another array easily for arbitrary array dimensions?

Comment: Can I ask why you need to do this. Can you not just allocate `B` at the same time as `A` (or at least in the same scope, when you will have access to the array bounds/shape parameters used to allocate `A`). Alternatively, if you are passing `A` into a function or subroutine you can you not just have an assumed size array `B` local to that routine which assumes the shape of `A`?

Comment: Well, I suppose I don't NEED this, it's just really inelegant.
The array `A` is allocated in a different .f file with the boundaries `A(nlmx-a_offset:nlpx+b_offset, ...)`, you'll note that this is more characters than using l/ubound.

Comment: Then I think M.S.B.'s answer is probably the best way to go about doing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of Fortran 2008, there is now the `MOLD` optional argument:

`ALLOCATE(B, MOLD=A)`

> The MOLD= specifier works almost in the same way as SOURCE=. If you specify MOLD= and source_expr is a variable, its value need not be defined. In addition, MOLD= does not copy the value of source_expr to the variable to be allocated.

Source: [IBM Fortran Ref](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSAT4T_15.1.1/com.ibm.xlf1511.lelinux.doc/language_ref/alloc.html)

Answer (score 9):

You can either define it in a preprocessor directive, but that will be with a fixed dimensionality:

```
#define DIMS3D(my_array) lbound(my_array,1):ubound(my_array,1),lbound(my_array,2):ubound(my_array,2),lbound(my_array,3):ubound(my_array,3)

allocate(B(DIMS3D(A)))
```

don't forget to compile with e.g. the `-cpp` option (gfortran)

If using Fortran 2003 or above, you can use the source argument:

```
allocate(B, source=A)
```

but this will also copy the elements of A to B.

Answer (score 5):

If you are doing this a lot and think it too ugly, you could write your own subroutine to take care of it, `copy_dims (template, new_array)`, encapsulating the source code line you show.   You could even set up a generic interface so that it could handle arrays of several ranks -- see [how to write wrapper for 'allocate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257248/how-to-write-wrapper-for-allocate/2258805) for an example of that concept.

Comment: yes, moving stuff to dedicated subroutines is very good if you will use it a lot and if you need some flexibility!