# Array of derived type: select entry

Tags: arrays, fortran, derived-types

Currently in my code I have a 2D array

```
integer, allocatable :: elements(:,:)
```

and define some constants

```
integer, parameter :: TYP = 1
integer, parameter :: WIDTH = 2
integer, parameter :: HEIGHT = 3
! ...
integer, parameter :: NUM_ENTRIES = 10
```

and allocate something like

```
allocate(elements(NUM_ENTRIES,10000))
```

so I can access elements like

```
write(*,*) elements(WIDTH,100) ! gives the width of the 100th element
```

Now I would like to have not only integer but a mixture of types for every element.
So I define a derived type

```
type Element
    logical active
    integer type
    real width
    ! etc
end type
```

and use an array of Elements

```
type(Element), allocatable :: elements(:)
```

With the 2d array version I could call a subroutine telling it which entry to use.
E.g.

```
subroutine find_average(entry, avg)
    integer, intent(in) :: entry   
    real, intent(out) :: avg
    integer i, 
    real s

    s = 0
    do i = lbound(elements,1), ubound(elements,1)
        if (elements(TYP,i) .gt. 0) s = s + elements(entry,i)
    end do
    avg = s/(ubound(elements,1)-lbound(elements,1))
end subroutine
```

So I could `call find_average(HEIGHT)` to find the average height or pass `WIDTH` to get the average width.
(And my subroutines do more advanced things than finding the average height or width, this is just an example.)

Question: How can I use different types (as with the derived type) but also reuse my functions to work with different entries (as in the example subroutine)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the array case, instead of passing in arguments array and index i, you could pass in the single argument array (i).  When you switch to having the derived type, similarly you could pass in  variable_of_type % element rather than passing in the entire variable_of_type and somehow instructing the procedure which subelement it is supposed to work on.   If the code needs to be different for the different types of elements (e.g., logical, integer, real), then you could write specific procedures for each, but call then with a common name via a generic interface block.  The compiler has to be able to distinguish the procedures of the generic interface block by some characteristic of the arguments, here their type.   For a code example in which the distinguishing characteristic is array rank see [how to write wrapper for 'allocate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257248/how-to-write-wrapper-for-allocate)

EDIT: example code.   does this do what you want?

```
module my_subs

   implicit none

   interface my_sum
      module procedure sum_real, sum_int
   end interface my_sum

contains

subroutine sum_real (array, tot)
   real, dimension(:), intent (in) :: array
   real, intent (out) :: tot
   integer :: i

   tot = 1.0
   do i=1, size (array)
      tot = tot * array (i)
   end do
end subroutine sum_real

subroutine sum_int (array, tot)
   integer, dimension(:), intent (in) :: array
   integer, intent (out) :: tot
   integer :: i

   tot = 0
   do i=1, size (array)
      tot = tot + array (i)
   end do
end subroutine sum_int

end module my_subs


program test_dt

use my_subs

implicit none

type my_type
   integer weight
   real length
end type my_type

type (my_type), dimension (:), allocatable :: people
type (my_type) :: answer

allocate (people (2))

people (1) % weight = 1
people (1) % length = 1.0
people (2) % weight = 2
people (2) % length = 2.0

call my_sum ( people (:) % weight, answer % weight )
write (*, *)  answer % weight

call my_sum ( people (:) % length, answer % length )
write (*, *)  answer % length

end program test_dt
```

Comment: `entry` will always point to an entry of the same type (say always `real`), so luckily this problem I will not have. But the first two sentences are not clear to me. For the array case, do you mean I could give the slice `elements(WIDTH,:)` to the function? For the derived type case, I do not want one element, I need all elements. Could you append a modified version of my example function, so I understand what you mean? Thanks

Comment: It is passing all elements of a given sub-item of a user defined type.  If necessary, Fortran can select different procedures depending on the type of the the sub-item.  How does this differ from what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it *does* solve my problem. (I could swear it was a different code yesterday, but the edit history says it was not *g*). So the main trick then is using the `(:)` in `type_array(:)%member` gives an array of the type of member. Nice! Thanks for you help!