# Assigning to Deferred Length String Data Type Component

Tags: fortran

The following code gives errors in both GFortran and Intel Fortran but seems perfectly reasonable and unambiguous.

GFortran error is

> Component to the right of a part reference with non-zero rank must not have the allocatable attribute

```
program vls

type :: tString
  character(:), allocatable :: S
end type

type(tString) :: Strings(2)

  Strings%S = 'xxx'

end program
```

I get not being able to assign to an allocatable array, but not to an allocatable scalar. Is this really what the standard demands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the prohibition applies to any allocatable object, not just arrays.  In Fortran 2018 this is the constraint C919:

> There shall not be more than one *part-ref* with nonzero rank. A *part-name* to the right of a *part-ref* with nonzero rank shall not have the ALLOCATABLE or POINTER attribute

In the case of this component of deferred length, it'll be hard to accept it being allowed while accepting the restriction for a deferred size array.  But the allocatable attribute wouldn't be allowed even if it were of constant length (even of length 1).

Comment: I don't really see why it should be hard to accept unless there are some obscure cases where the syntax would be ambiguous or undesirable.

Comment: Anyway, lest I seem ungrateful, upvote for making the effort of digging out the standard reference of me. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why you "get not being able to assign to an allocatable array", in that case, as something like `x(:)%j=[1,2,3]` for example has much the same trouble.  Admittedly, it isn't entirely obvious why there is a syntax difficulty with this: the restriction is more to do with "making things easier for compilers".  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27183800/3157076) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not buying into Vladimir F's memory mapping explanation. If I can change the syntax to a simple do loop, the compiler should be able to do the same without much trouble. Fortran's array notation is one of its few selling points over other languages and to put this sort of restriction on the syntax for no good reason doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: There are a lot of subtle issues here.  Perhaps if you'd really like to explore them, you could ask another question explicitly about that?  There are people involved in compiler development answering Fortran questions here who could give an awful lot of detail.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply "moving too fast". `Strings` is a vector of type `tString` and of length 2.

You cannot assign directly to `Strings%S` (that could loosely correspond to all attributes `S` in the vector `Strings`.

Assign instead to `Strings(1)%S` for the first entry, for instance.

```
program vls

  type :: tString
     character(:), allocatable :: S
  end type tString

  type(tString) :: Strings(2)

  Strings(1)%S = 'xxx'

  write(*,*) Strings(1)%S

end program vls
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pierre. It isn't just loosely corresponding to all the fields in the vector, it is completely corresponding to it, which is exactly what I want to do! I can use the same syntax OK with an intrinsic scalar but not a deferred length scalar string, which seems rather arbitrary.

Comment: Only array members whose type is simple and size fixed for all elements (which is of course not the case here) can be assigned so. I wrote "loosely" precisely because I understood your intent and knew that it did not fit Fortran's specification.