# Reason of extra flexibility when using fortran intrinsics

Tags: function, fortran

Suppose I have defined a function f(x)=x**2 using real variables in fortran, and I define two arrays x(100) and y(100) where x(i)=real(i),say.

Now, to load all the values of a function in the array y(100), if I use an intrinsic(say sin), I have to only write

```
y=sin(x)
```

But, to load f(x) I shall have to write

```
do i=1,100
y(i)=f(x(i))
enddo
```

If I use

```
y=f(x)
```

it will give an scalar vector rank mismatch error. 
In what way shall I have to define the function such that it can also be used just like the sin intrinsic?

Moreover, in the intrinsic sin, I can use both real and complex as arguments, but it cannot be done in the user defined function and will give type mismatch error(real complex).
What is the reason of those extra flexibility in the intrinsic functions and how to define my own functions to mimic the intrinsics?

Comment: You should learn **elemental procedures**. Most intrinsics are elemental and you can declare your own.

Comment: For the second part of the question, you can write multiple functions that differ by type, kind or rank in their arguments, then an interface that defines a common name.  You then can call by the common name and the compiler will distinguish by the argument, calling the specific function.   See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257248/how-to-write-wrapper-for-allocate/2258805

Comment: Voted to reopen as the given duplicate doesn't answer the entire question

Comment: @IanBush Which part of the question? Both generic functions and elemental suctions were treated there. We should at least keep the link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786965/subroutine-argument-with-unknown-rank-shape-in-fortran?noredirect=1&lq=1 Also, why not just another duplicate target that is more about generics?

Comment: I could see how to address different ranks, but not different datatypes - yes, it is covered by generics, but the way I read the answers to the linked questions was that they focused purely on the multiple rank case, and not the different data types

Comment: That can always be another duplicate target added. Of course, we can write an answer about elemental generic, grab the rep points nad so ... but I do not think it is ethical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Work on different ranks

**TLDR**:
You greatly improve your code, if you declare all procedures as `pure` or `elemental` if possible.
By doing so, you automatically get most of the behaviour of intrinsic functions.

A procedure (function or subroutine) can be `pure` if it has no side effects.
A function has the additional constraint, that it may not have `out` or `inout` arguments.

If you have a `pure` procedure, that acts only on scalar values, you can declare it as `elemental`. This will signal to the compiler, that the execution of this procedure on one element of an array is completely independent from the execution on other array elements.
This will allow you the same syntactic sugar, as intrinsic functions. Note that `elemental` procedures can have even several arguments.
Some compilers will even use the `elemental` information to automatically parallelize the execution.

An example:

```
! implicit none is assumed
real elemental function double_pow(x, n)
    real, intent(in) :: x
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    double_pow = x**(2 * n)
end function

double_pow(2., 2) == 2.**(2 * 2)
double_pow([1. 2.], 2) == [1.**(2 * 2), 2.**(2 * 2)]
! in the last case, the arrays have to have the same shape
double_pow([1. 2.], [1, 2]) == [1.**(1 * 2), 2.**(2 * 2)]
```

Note 1:
There is still one big difference between elemental and intrinsic procedures.
Even elemental functions cannot be used to initialize `parameter` variables (compile time constants.)

```
! possible
real, parameter :: PI = atan(1.0) * 4.0
! not possible
real, parameter :: four = double_pow(2.0, 1)
```

Note 2:
Some statements with side-effects (e.g. `error stop`) are allowed in `pure` procedures. 
In addition, `pure subroutines` may have `inout` arguments so they are not exactly pure in the computer science sense.

## Work on different datatypes

You have to create a generic interface for two different functions acting on different datatypes.
As noted in the comments, there are already several answers to that question:

Just a short example

```
module test_mod
    implicit none(type, external)
    private
    public :: double

    interface double
        module procedure double_real, double_integer
    end interface

contains
    real pure function double_real(x)
        real, intent(in) :: x
        double_real = 2.0 * x
    end function

    integer elemental function double_integer(x)
        integer, intent(in) :: x
        double_integer = 2 * x
    end function
end module
```