# Fortran interface, procedure and function relationship

Tags: fortran, fortran90, generic-programming

I'm reading some Fortran 90 code and come across some concepts that I'm not familiar with.
Part of the code, which is defined to calculate dot product of two vectors, `dmf_dotp` for real value, `zmf_dotp` for complex ones.

`mesh.F90`:

```
#include mesh_inc.F90

interface dmf_dotp
  module procedure dmf_dotp_1, dmf_dotp_2
end interface dmf_dotp

interface zmf_dotp
  module procedure zmf_dotp_1, zmf_dotp_2
end interface zmf_dotp
```

In another file there are functions like:

```
R_TYPE function X(mf_dotp_1)(mesh, f1, f2, reduce, dotu) result(dotp)
R_TYPE function X(mf_dotp_2)(mesh, dim, f1, f2, reduce, dotu) result(dotp)
```

Then one can call these functions(or interfaces?) with `zmf_dotp` or `dmf_dotp`. So what's really going on here?

---

Edit thanks to [Vladimir F](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565588/fortran-interface-procedure-and-function-relationship#comment43556722_27565588). It turns out there are some preprocessor macros defined else:

```
#define X(x)        z ## x
#define R_TYPE      CMPLX
```

Comment: You should show more, `R_TYPE` and `X` are probably preprocessor macros. How are they defined? How are those two files connected? Is there an `include` statement?

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks! Carefully read the code and found include file. Also in your comment to another question, I learned that '##' is used for string concatenation.

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257248/how-to-write-wrapper-for-allocate

Comment: @M.S.B. Thanks! Got so much to learn about Fortran.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the ways one can do generic programming in Fortran without copy and paste everything.

I assume it actually looks similar to:

```
#define X(x)        z ## x
#define R_TYPE      CMPLX
#include mesh_inc.F90
```

and

```
#define X(x)        d ## x
#define R_TYPE      FLOAT
#include mesh_inc.F90
```

or similar, it seems that `CMPLX` is another macro which leads to  some kind of `complex` and therefore I expect FLOAT to be some kind of `real`, possibly `double precision`.

This will actually lead for the preprocessed source code as

```
 double precision function dmf_dotp_1(...)
```

and

```
 double complex function zmf_dotp_1(...)
```

with the functions having similar or even identical body.

This enables you to write the relevant code only once and create reuse with under different names with different types.

Beware! The very popular gfortran compiler runs the C preprocessor in the "traditional mode" which does not support the `##` operator.

Comment: So do you have a work around for using a similar approach with gfortran?

Comment: Yes, run cpp before gfortran.